# How to retrieve session cookies in getServerSideProps using next js & firebase

Tags: express, next.js

Im using firebase for authentication in a nextjs project. I'm generating a session cookie using firebase admin SDK on an express backend API running on localhost on a different port.

```
const cookie = await this.createSessionCookie(req.body.token)
    if(cookie) {
      // set cookie expiration
      const expiresIn = 60 * 60 * 24 * 5 * 1000;
      // Set cookie policy for session cookie.
      const cookieOptions = { maxAge: expiresIn, httpOnly: true, secure: true, path: '/'};
      res.cookie('session', cookie, cookieOptions);
      res.end(JSON.stringify(
        {
          "message": "User created successfully",
          "status": "success",
          "data": { result }
        }
      ));
    }
```

However I am unable to retrieve the cookie in getServerSideProps in nextJS.

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const cookies = nookies.get(context)
  if (!cookies.session) {
    context.res.writeHead(302, { Location: '/auth/signin' })
    context.res.end()
  }
  return {
   props: {}
  }
}
```

I understand this is a result of the same-origin policy since the next app and backend API are on different ports on localhost. Is there a way I can retrieve the cookies in the next app?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to set the cookie option secure to false since I was on localhost. After this I was able to set the cookie.